# Posting data to http iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to send an email address(will be getting from textfield) to http url by clicking a send button from an application which is already logged in at the same http server.
How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: You should search here. This question has been answered many many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can do this with [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library. here is a sample code

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Comment: thanx @Ayaz I have checked it .. but it would be good if i use native methods

Comment: library handles lots of stuff for us